# Mojarra 2.2 versions diverging

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra, versions

https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/2.2/releasenotes.html lists two diverging version branches of JSF2.2 where, strangely, 2.2.8-xx seems to be more recent than 2.2.9 and above.

Some bugs are fixed only in 2.2.9 (https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3384), some only in 2.2.8-xx (https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4111) and some in both versions (https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3133).

Whats the reason behind this and which branch should I use in production? Both seem to contain important bugfixes.

I could not find anything about this with google. Maybe the mojarra guys could add some information to the release notes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mojarra 2.2.8-xx releases are built specifically for Oracle WebLogic 12c with handpicked bugfixes from newer releases backported every time. WebLogic has namely a bug in its integrated Weld version which made it incompatible with Mojarra 2.2.9 and newer where the fix for [issue 3345](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/3345) was introduced.

If you aren't using WebLogic 12c, then just ignore the 2.2.8-xx releases altogether and pick the newest 2.2.x which is as of today 2.2.14. If you're however using WebLogic 12c, then you should actually focus on obtaining a maintenance pack from Oracle WebLogic support. It'll bundle the newer Mojarra 2.2.8-xx version.

As reference: I'm a [Mojarra committer](https://projects.eclipse.org/content/bauke-scholtz-committer-eclipse-mojarra).